# How to add list having map in YAML using yq

Tags: yaml, yq

How to add list having map in YAML using yq , I also need to use properties file for input

I have below yaml:

```
apiVersion: core.oci.upbound.io/v1alpha1
kind: Instance
metadata:
  name: crossplane-inst-flat
spec:
  forProvider:
    compartmentIdRef:
      name: compartment-oke-shu
    createVnicDetails:
      - subnetIdRef:
          name: crossplane-srg-subnet
    availabilityDomain: "yyy:PHX-AD-1"
    shape: "VM.Standard2.1"
    sourceDetails:
      - sourceId: ocid1.image.oc1.phx.7ytytytytytyt
        sourceType: "image"
    displayName: crossplane-inst-flat
```

I want to change below name value:

```
createVnicDetails:
  - subnetIdRef:
      name: crossplane-srg-subnet
```

And source id in below section also the other map should persist as well

```
    sourceDetails:
      - sourceId: ocid1.image.oc1.phx.7ytytytytytyt
```

Using below config.properties syntax:

```
spec.forProvider.createVnicDetails.subnetIdRef.name=test
spec.forProvider.sourceDetails.sourceId=ocid1.image.oc1.phx.hhhh
spec.forProvider.sourceDetails.sourceType=image
```

sh file expression:

```
 '. *= load_props("/compute.properties")' config.yaml
```

but they are not working as expected, the list -(dash) is missing.
how to do this without sed

Comment: Which yq are you using ([see tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/yq/info))?

Comment: same: https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/usage/properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your paths are missing the sequence indexes.

These expressions do what you want:

```
.spec.forProvider.createVnicDetails[].subnetIdRef.name = "test"
.spec.forProvider.sourceDetails[].sourceId = "ocid1.image.oc1.phx.hhhh"
.spec.forProvider.sourceDetails[].sourceType = "image"
```

You may want to use `[0]` instead of `[]` if you explicitly want to only update the first sequence item.

You can specify these in property syntax:

```
spec.forProvider.createVnicDetails.0.subnetIdRef.name=test
spec.forProvider.sourceDetails.0.sourceId=ocid1.image.oc1.phx.hhhh
spec.forProvider.sourceDetails.0.sourceType=image
```

Comment: thanks for response but I already tried .. it is not working.  given below output at the end of yaml:

    createVnicDetails[]:
      subnetIdRef:
        name: test
    sourceDetails[]:
      sourceId: ocid1.image.oc1.phx.hhhh
      sourceType: image

Comment: Updated for proper syntax, didn't realize you're using property syntax. The expressions I give work now directly in `yq`, I don't know about properties but obviously you'd need to inject the sequence index there as well.

Comment: my path is correct as have non list keys which are working fine

Comment: i need this in properties file only, that was my logic

Comment: expression i am using in sh:  '. *= load_props("/compute.properties")' config.yaml

Comment: Updated with property syntax, tested and works

Comment: i tried same before but it was not working and now its working .. strange .. thanks .. 
how can i add double quote here spec.forProvider.sourceDetails.0.sourceType=image .. any idea?  image not printing as double quotes

Comment: `with(.spec.forProvider.sourceDetails[].sourceType; . = "image" | . style="double")` gives you a double-quoted scalar but that only works directly with `yq`, not as property. Properties don't know about YAML styles.